# Moving the Google Drive Application Data

Tags: windows, windows-registry, authentication, google-drive

I'm trying to setup google drive to work on my university's lab computers. The set up we have uses a virtual disk and a dummy user. Whenever a user logs in, windows is preloaded with a fresh image and we mount a network drive on H: and when they log out, everything is blown away for the next user.

When we install google drive, it defaults the drive folder to My Documents (which we mapped to H:) but it also adds an application data folder under C:\Documents and Settings\username\local Settings (and I presume the equivalent path in win7 which we have a team testing for roll out in the fall). This folder keeps a record of the file changes and google drive wont work without it. But since its on the C: drive, it gets deleted at logout. I need a way to move it to the H:

The second issue is with the authentication. When a user logs in, google drive stores the credentials somewhere in the registry but I can't seem to find all the pieces. We would need these keys to be reloaded into the registry at login and exported to the H: at logout to simulate a stable configuration.

Can't seem to find a simple answer and I don't really want to write a custom app using the API to replace the google drive client on our campus machines.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution here is going to be a full fledged roaming profile setup. http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc738596(v=ws.10).aspx

Anything short of that is going to be a kludge that's subject to breakage anytime that Google 
Drive updates, as well as being a lot more work than moving to roaming profiles.

This has the additional benefit that personal settings for other applications can follow users from computer to computer. Your reimaging solution described above already takes care of the primary drawback of roaming profiles (accumulation of old profiles), so this might be workable for you.